# check to see if the Chapter Title has been referenced two or more times before a different Chapter Title is referenced? then apply a different class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of divs sprinkled throughout a long article. Each one, when clicked, shows a `span` of hidden text within the div. They're made up of

1) chapter title
2) section number
3) point number

eg: government 3:15 OR whitehouse 15:27 OR legislation 1:38 (there are over 90 chapters).

Using jQuery, i'm trying to see if a chapter title occurs two or more times in a row, if it does, apply a specific class to every one except the first.

Reason being: when referencing these chapter titles, i've placed an icon at the beginning:

eg: `(icon)Whitehouse 29:8`, but I don't want every single chapter title to have an icon, if that chapter title is referenced two or more times before another chapter title is referenced, then I want the second third forth(etc.) to not have the icon.

**Does anyone know how I would go about checking to see if the Chapter Title has been referenced two or more times before a different Chapter Title is referenced?**

**example:**

He spoke of the many injustices in `(icon)Whitehouse 3:15`, but the president wasn't speaking of mountains `whitehouse 4:2` and `whitehouse 4:9`. When he saw they were ready to begin `(icon)congress 19:4`, he said "welcome all to this session" `(icon)legislation 9:41`, then smacked the prime minister in the face `legislation 3:8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate all references in a set of span tags (or any other container) with a common attribute, but in this case let's say `span.ref`.

I've got a basic version of it as the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GoranMottram/GqYzS/).

The HTML required for each chapter title requires the following format:

```
<span class="ref">
    <img src="..." />
    <span class="ref-title">Washington</span>
    1:23
</span>
```

Then use the following jQuery to update the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // var to store the previous reference title
    var previousRefTitle = '';

    // cycle through each reference on the page
    $('.ref').each(function(){

        // if chapter title is the same as the previous reference
        if ($(this).children('.ref-title').text() == previousRefTitle)
        {
            // change the class
            if ($(this).hasClass('ref'))
            {
                $(this).removeClass('ref');
                $(this).addClass('ref-following');    
            }
        }

        // if chapter title is new compared to the previous reference
        else
        {
            // update var for next iteration
            previousRefTitle = $(this).children('.ref-title').text();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: But its not just the first reference on the page i need the icon attached to, its the first on sequential chapter titles, see the example at the bottom of my question. Your idea of adding classes sounds great, your code will add the child-ref class to every reference after the first one on the page.

Comment: @android.nick - Ahh now I see, sorry about that. I've done many things like what you've described before and I always implement it by using a var (out of the loop scope) to store the state of a previous iteration, so that I can compare it with the current iteration. I've updated the code in the answer and provided a demo.